# Get Set of entries from a Map

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

Given a map such as:

```
Map<String, Integer> = new Hashmap<String, Integer>;
```

How can I get a `Collection<Integer>` (any implementation of Collection would do) of the entrySet?  Doing `.entrySet()` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: -1, this question does not show any research effort: even a quick look through Map's Javadoc would have answered this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to get just the map values you can use the `values()` method.  The Javadoc page is [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29).

This is because your requirement is a Collection of Integers and the map values are of Integer type.

`entrySet` returns a collection of `Map.Entry`, each instance of which contains both the key and value that make up the entry, so if you want both the key and value, use `entrySet()` like so

`Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries = map.entrySet()`

Comment: `Set` actually _doesn't_ have any methods that aren't on `Collection`, interestingly enough. It just has different semantics.

Comment: @colind, thanx, don't know how my wires got crossed there.

Answer (score 6):

That depends on if you truly want a SET. If you want a true Set you must do:

```
Set mySet = new HashSet(map.values());
```

Notice that **values** gives a Collection which can have duplicate entries.