# how to access httpRequest data in servlet using Map?

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest

```
**jsp Code**

<html>

<body>
<form action="test.do">
Name:<input type="text" name="name"/>
Sname:<input type="text" name="sname"/>
<input type="submit" value="sub">
</form>
</body>
</html>

**Servlet Code**
@WebServlet("/test.do")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Map hm=arg0.getParameterMap();
    //System.out.println("Map"+hm);
    Set s=hm.keySet();

    //System.out.println("SET"+s);
    Iterator it=s.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        String key="";
        Object obj=it.next();
        key=(String)obj;
        System.out.println(key);
        Object obj1=hm.get(key);
    String val[]=(String[])obj1;
        System.out.println(key+"...."+val);
        }

}
}
```

When i am using this code I am able to access Key but not values.I am getting values in Ljava.lang.String;@199832c   form!!

How i can store all data from request and store in Map.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot post an answer maybe?

Comment: yes after adding this code i m able to access values.. thnks    for(int i=0;i<val.length;i++){
  System.out.println(key+"...."+val[i]);}

Answer (score 1):

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477480/get-set-of-entries-from-a-map), you can get the values using the `values` method. Alternatively, you can get each entry of a map using [entrySet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). The code to iterate through your entrySet looks like:

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Map<String, String[]) hm=arg0.getParameterMap();
    //System.out.println("Map"+hm);
    Set<Map.Entry<String, String[]>> s=hm.entrySet();
    for (Map.Entry<String,String[]> e:s) {
       System.err.println(String.format("%s maps to %s"), e.getKey(), Arrays.toString(e.getValue()));
    }
```

If you should have further problems, leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The method [ServletRequest#getParameterMap()](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29) returns you `java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String[]>`. You can get the individual values from the `String[]` by using simple Java code, iterating the `String[]` using a loop.

You are printing the `String[]` array `val` hence you get such a String `Ljava.lang.String;@199832c` , because it uses the default implementation of `toString()` defined in `Object` ! You can use `Arrays.toString(val)` instead to print the actual contents of the array.